# Need help on table formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have the following code in index.html. When this page is executed, a page is displayed 
with login & logout buttons, when the user clicks on login another page div=AuthBody gets displayed , now when the user provides the credentials and clicks on the login button, it connects to the database and writes the data to the table div element, but the results are not displayed in the same look and feel just like the previous two pages

How can i ensure the table results are displayed in the same area/look and feel as in the first two pages ?

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>index</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
    </head>

<body style="display: none;">

    <div id="AppBody">  
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Custom Login Module</h1>
            </div>  

            <div class="wrapper1">
                <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="getSecretData()" />
                <input type="button" value="Logout" onclick="WL.Client.logout('CustomAuthenticatorRealm',{onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp})" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="AuthBody" style="display: none">

            <div id="loginForm">
                Username:<br/>
                <input type="text" id="usernameInputField" /><br />
                Password:<br/>
                <input type="password" id="passwordInputField" /><br/>      
                <input type="button" id="loginButton" value="Login" />
                <input type="button" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
     </div>     

     <div id="ResTable"  style="display: none">

        <div class="header">
        My Dispute List 
        </div>

        <div class="wrapper"> 

    <table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow"  id="mytable">
        <thead>

           <tr id="loadChat">
              <th data-priority="1">Dispute Number</th>
              <th data-priority="2">Status</th>
              <th data-priority="3">Start Date</th>
              <th data-priority="4">Customer Name</th>
              <th data-priority="5">DRO</th>
              <th data-priority="6">Dispute Manager</th>

           </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

java script code that writes the data to table

```
var mytabledata = "<table><tr><th> DISPUTE NUMBER </th>" + "<th>DISPUTE STATUS    </th>" + "<th>START DATE </th>" + "<th>CUSTOMER NAME </th>" + "<th>     DRO      </th>" + "<th>DISPUTE MANAGER   </th>";

if (result.invocationResult.resultSet.length > 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < result.invocationResult.resultSet.length; j++) {
        var row = $("<tr />");
        row.append($("<td>" + result.invocationResult.resultSet[j].DISP_NUMBER + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + result.invocationResult.resultSet[j].DISP_STATUS + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + result.invocationResult.resultSet[j].DISP_CREATE_DATE + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + result.invocationResult.resultSet[j].CUST_CONT_NAME + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + result.invocationResult.resultSet[j].DISP_RES_OWNER + "</td>"));
        row.append($("<td>" + result.invocationResult.resultSet[j].DISP_MANAGER + "</td>"));
        $("#loadChat").append(row);
        $('#AppBody').hide();
        $('#AuthBody').hide();
        $('#ResTable').show();
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide the images as links in the comments and I'll edit the question with them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Your code is adding broken HTML code into `thead` which should not contain each result data but title of each elements.

try this

```
for (var j = 0; j < result.invocationResult.resultSet.length; j++) {
    var tmp = "<tr>";
    var resSet = result.invocationResult.resultSet[j];
    for(res in resSet){
        tmp += "<td>" + resSet[res] + "</td>";
    }
    $("#mytable > tbody").append(tmp+"</tr>");
}
```

and in HTML

```
    <thead>

       <tr id="loadChat">
          <th data-priority="1">Dispute Number</th>
          <th data-priority="2">Status</th>
          <th data-priority="3">Start Date</th>
          <th data-priority="4">Customer Name</th>
          <th data-priority="5">DRO</th>
          <th data-priority="6">Dispute Manager</th>

       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- database result would be here -->
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hello Suish, 

Thanks for the quick response. The above code is working but, the row values are not coming under correct columns. How do I ensure the right value comes under right columns ?

Thanks..Johnson

Comment: Just one more question. Why am I seeing the background color as white when the table data is displayed ? How do I get a JQuery mobile look ? I mean the background like in the login page. 

Thanks..Johnson

Answer (score 0):

Basic structure of jQuery Mobile table widget is as follow. You have missed `tbody` part.

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>info 1</th>
      <th>info 1</th>
      <th>info 1</th>
    <tr>
    <tr>
      <th>info 2</th>
      <th>info 2</th>
      <th>info 2</th>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Moreover, when you update table's details dynamically, you need to `rebuild` the table.

```
$("#mytable").table("rebuild");
```

An example of a dynamic table.

```
var data = [{
    "DISP_NUMBER": "1",
        "DISP_STATUS": "online",
        "DISP_CREATE_DATE": "01/02/2014",
        "name": "John"
}, {
    "DISP_NUMBER": "2",
        "DISP_STATUS": "offline",
        "DISP_CREATE_DATE": "10/05/2014",
        "name": "Dao"

}, {
    "DISP_NUMBER": "3",
        "DISP_STATUS": "offline",
        "DISP_CREATE_DATE": "10/05/2014",
        "name": "Anonymous"
}];

$.each(data, function (i, value) {
    var row = $("<tr />");
    row.append($("<th>" + value.DISP_NUMBER + "</th>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + value.DISP_STATUS + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + value.DISP_CREATE_DATE + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + value.name + "</td>"));

    /* append to tobody */
    $("#mytable tbody").append(row);
});

/* rebuild table and column-toggle */ 
$("#mytable").table("rebuild");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3rft6nbw/)**

Comment: Hello Omar, 

Thanks for you response. Being able to display the data in a tabular format, now I need to provide link to Dispute Number in all the rows. So when clicks on the Dispute Number link, he should be taken to another page with dispute details, where I want to provide a drop down with some options like 'Accept' or 'Reject' dispute. Can you please guide me how I can accomplish this ?

Thanks..

Comment: @user3646990 Hi, this is a separate issue. Please post a new question with relevant details.