# Responsive table looses responsiveness when populating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile responsive table. When resizing the browser window, more/less columns show up, so everything works fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/BamBamm/fe4ppftm/1/

```
<table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive" id="customerTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-priority="6">customer ID</th>
      <th>Customer name</th>
      <th data-priority="1">First name</th>
      <th data-priority="2">Address</th>
      <th data-priority="3">City</th>
      <th data-priority="4">PostalCode</th>
      <th data-priority="5">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="customerTableBody">
    <tr>
      <td>10801</td>
      <td>Some name</td>
      <td>Some firt name</td>
      <td>Some address</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>123456</td>
      <td>United Kingdom</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When I try to populate the table dynamically though, the responsive table is not responsive anymore when resizing the browser. I'm filling the table via setting the html code of the table body:
http://jsfiddle.net/BamBamm/e2ukzy5z/1/

```
tableBody = "<tr><td>10801</td> <td>Some name</td> <td>Some firt name</td> <td>Some address</td> <td>London</td> <td>123456</td> <td>United Kingdom</td> </tr>";
$('#customerTableBody').html(tableBody);
```

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25346522/1771795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to call Refresh after you add new rows.

$('#customerTable').table( "refresh" )

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5570

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/BamBamm/e2ukzy5z/2/

Comment: It works by calling the refresh method on the entire table (instead of the body). Thank you for the great link. http://jsfiddle.net/BamBamm/e2ukzy5z/3/

      $('#customerTable').table( "refresh" );